# iOS - resetting NSMutable Array causes crash

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have an NSMutableArray I'm trying to reload after an async call. The first time it loads like this:

```
self.sessionProcList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[result records]];
```

After the user does some interaction, the same line will be reached to reload the NSMutableArray. This causes the crash

**Header file has:**

```
@interface...
NSMutableArray *sessionProcList;
... }

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sessionProcList;
```

Comment: are you sure that you should use nonatomic in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. I've been searching for a good example of reusing a NSMutableArray and resetting the value between operations w/ no luck. It's a pretty simple screen. Just reloads the array values. 

What would be the easiest way to declare that? Instead of the approach I'm using. The approach I have works fine for a synchronized singleton, but doesn't seem to work in a single interface class.

Comment: echoing Joshua, what is the output of the crash?  What do you see in the debugger?  I'd also check to see that [result records] isn't returning nil.

Answer (score 1):

Say you do:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject: [[NSObject alloc] init]];
NSObject *o = [a objectAtIndex: 0];
[a removeAllObjects];
[o description]; // *BOOM*
```

The above will [generally -- sometimes not but only by coincidence] crash because `o` has been deallocated by the time the `description` method is invoked.

If you have a reference to an object in an array, but have not retained said reference, then said object may be deallocated out from under you when you empty the array.

(And `nonatomic` vs. atomic is irrelevant.)

Comment: Doesn't [[NSObject alloc] init] cause a retain?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I would say that elements in that array are being referenced from somewhere else. Resetting the array causes the items using the references to crash.

I would check your application for other variables, properties, or UI elements using those variables that have not been release before resetting it.

Comment: Thanks jocull! I think I may be not totally getting where to release it. I have a few of these types of calls to items in the array. ZKSObject *tmpSessionProc = [self.sessionProcList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

If I release that, I get a "message sent to deallocated instance" crash. What am I missing? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think you need to release *tmpSessionProc because you didn't alloc that variable there. It's referenced from self.sessionProcList, so if you release it at *tmpSessionProc you also release it in self.sessionProcList. You may try some debugging by using the developer console in XCode with something like NSLog("Retain count: %i", [tmpSessionProc retainCount]);

Answer (score 0):

Because `arrayWithArray` is a convenience method it gets initialised with an autorelease flag.

You haven't mentioned what the crash / error message is but I am guessing your NSMutableArray is getting released before your second iteraction with it starts.

Try and retain the array for however long you need it with:

```
self.sessionProcList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[result records]];
[sessionProcList retain];
```

And then release it when you're done with it:

```
[sessionProcList release];
```

I hope it helps.
Rog

Comment: If you use the property, which is a retain property, you don't need to retain it again.  This is not the issue causing the crash.